# $u_t+\frac{x}{t}u_x=0$ for $t>1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$$u_t+\frac{x}{t}u_x=0,\hspace{20mm}t>1,-\infty<x<\infty,$$
where the initial data is given at $t=t_0$ at $t=1$ and we have $u(x,t=1)=u_{in}(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

I used method of characteristics. I find that $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x}{t}\implies x=ct$. Now, I have $c=\frac{x}{t}$, so my solution would be $u(x,t)=u_{in}(\frac{x}{t})=e^{-(\frac{x}{t})^2}$. Could someone please tell me if I am correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Aryadeva thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Why asking if your solution is correct ? You can check yourself :
$$u(x,t)=e^{-(x/t)^2}$$
$$u_x=\frac{-2x}{t^2}e^{-(x/t)^2}$$
$$u_t=\frac{2x^2}{t^3}e^{-(x/t)^2}$$
$$u_t+\frac{x}{t}u_x=\left(\frac{2x^2}{t^3}e^{-(x/t)^2}\right)+\frac{x}{t}\left(\frac{-2x}{t^2}e^{-(x/t)^2}\right)=0$$
Thus $u=e^{-(x/t)^2}$ is solution of the PDE.
$$u(x,1)=e^{-(x/1)^2}=e^{-x^2}$$
Thus $u=e^{-(x/t)^2}$ satisfies the condition.